# How to access the second element that has the same class name in python

Tags: python-3.x

I have 2 elements on a web page that have the class with the same name, i use selenium and I have to call the second element, that I can't. How can I do?
I have tried to use the firts class you read of the code but it gives me that error:

```
Message: element click intercepted: Element <a class="navigate-target navigate-next"
```

First code:

```
<a class="navigate-target navigate-prev no-outline" href="..." title="..." data-track="prevPhotoButtonClick" data-action="ad" style="height: 430px;">
<span class="hide-text">←</span>
</a>
```

Second code (what i need):

```
<a class="navigate-target navigate-next no-outline" href="..." title="..." data-track="nextPhotoButtonClick" data-action="ad" style="height: 430px;">
<span class="hide-text">→</span>
</a>
```

This is my code, it's not perfect but work exept that thing

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import requests, time, os, bs4

os.chdir('/home/vices/Documents/Python/document_test/cats')
os.makedirs('/home/vices/Documents/Python/document_test/cats/Foto_salvate', exist_ok=True)

def download():
    chrome_options = Options()

    chrome_options.add_argument("incognito")
    chrome_options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)

    driver = webdriver.Chrome('/home/vices/Documents/Python/Driver/chromedriver', chrome_options=chrome_options)
    driver.get('https://flickr.com/')

    driver.find_element_by_id('search-field').click()
    driver.find_element_by_id('search-field').send_keys('husqvarna')
    driver.find_element_by_class_name('search-icon-button').click()
    time.sleep(2)
    driver.find_elements_by_class_name('photo-list-photo-interaction')[1].click()

    time.sleep(2)


    while True:
        url = driver.current_url
        print("Downloading page...")
        res = requests.get(url)
        res.raise_for_status()

        soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, features="lxml")
        foto = soup.select('img')
        foto_url = 'https:' + foto[1].get('src')

        print("Downloading foto")
        res = requests.get(foto_url)
        res.raise_for_status()

        imagefile = open(os.path.join('Foto_salvate', os.path.basename(foto_url)), 'wb')
        for chunk in res.iter_content(100000):
            imagefile.write(chunk)
        imagefile.close()

        driver.find_elements_by_class_name('hide-text')[1].click()




download()
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use: find_elements_by_class_name
as referenced here:

https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.find_elements_by_class_name

Then take the second element of the list in output.

Comment: I tried, the problem is after (I don't know why) it goes forward of an image and goes back of an image, without going into the following images